# How to get images from photo library without using ALAssetsLibrary?

Tags: ios, ios5, location, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

I want to implement a custom image picker with multiple images selection feature, just like an extension of the standard `UIImagepickerController`. I know I can use `ALAssetsLibrary` to enumerate the library groups, then enumerate the assets. However, accessing `ALAssetsLibrary` will ask to get the location services open for iOS 5 and iOS 4, which is not acceptable. So my question is: are there any ways to avoid asking location services open when accessing `ALAssetsLibrary`? Or other options not using `ALAssetsLibrary` to get the images? 
Thanks!

Comment: there is no other option

Comment: @Leena I think I've got a solution: Just extend the `UIImagePickerController` and place your own control above the view.